# How to properly type a return type that should infer a type from function arguments?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am stuck in trying to figure out how to type a return type for a function, which would return an object using the keys of generic type from one of the function arguments.

```js
type Input<A> = { [key: string]: A };
type Output<T> = { [key in keyof T]: null };

const track = <T extends string>(input: Input<T>): Output<typeof input> => {
  return Object.entries(input).reduce((previous, [key, val]) => ({
    ...previous,
    [key]: null,
  }), {} as Output<typeof input>);
}

type Test = 'union' | 'string';

const { one } = track<Test>({ one: 'union', two: 'string' });
```

I would like to be able to have autocomplete on `const { one }` to be able to see all of the keys that the `input` argument has, but it's not working. Another requirement would be to be able to specify the allowed values the `Input<A>` type can have.

I got it to work when I let typescript infer the `T extends string` type, but in my case it cannot be inferred and I would like to be able to pass it.

What am I doing wrong?

If I use `: Output<Input<T>>` then it also doesn't work, and I'm assuming that is because typescript is considering the `Input<T>` there to be something entirely different than the `input` argument with the same type (rightfully so).

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAPAQQHxQLxQN5QDaA1hCAFxQDOwATgJZwDmAupWlAL4DcAsAFChIUAPLIkqACpZcBEmSiMopEAHsAZlElsocRABt9XPvwEBjVXBpQ6AQzPEcUFJKgQAHsAhwAJlWp0jEwYABSMEpTwEi4YAJSUYsDRQhAaigjIMlh4AlBQtBDAiLRwogBGAFYQZsAAdN6BEFRhGcCxtQU+iGYQISFgBQBu9KqIVAA0RCqTg7b6LLE4WCE5-Hl5tZsDEMOjE7nr8iA6eobjB5yxk3icULb+icngqZrhmbEmnAICKVpNwE4AOSIOAjOCAqAAHyggJoDGYgJM5ks1gIlmgt1wdgcLn+oTRcAglGBoMsgMmwAA7qpiXCghDLkj+BYrKp9BBavpVEwQuiPkA)

Comment: In the future please use a TypeScript playground link which you can find [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q). I have edited the question to include one for you :)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/m3ydLw) meet your needs?  If not, what am I missing? If so, uh, I guess @AlexWayne answered basically this already.

Comment: @jcalz this approach loses the ability to specify the available strings that can be used in the Input type

Comment: [Using an intermediary function can do it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA8grsMCA8AVAfFAvFA3lAbQGsIQoBLAOyhJAHsAzKVAXQC4pK4AbbqAXwDcAWABQY0JGYQAzsGxQARHErk6lRVAA+SuQCcqAc0UjxogMbq5UYHoCG5ogrToAFAEpsmZDCgQAHsAQlAAmMniEtBz6RuzMAm5USMAcMO6pCMk+mFiYuGJQUHoQwHB61DAARgBWEObAAHTBtuSyrkkI7g3FIXDmEK6uYMUAbmpwMgA0kaTTI3bcLJ65UK75ooWFDdvDEGN0E5MFm8SkcVy8RxsC7tO4-FB24fCIKDDo7qb8YpaU1vjqaAPHC2BxENCyYBudxrKCAjgAchUakoCOmwAA7nRETFKIYETdTD8rHRuBAGtw6IZXIDPkA)

Comment: @Gustavs Please [edit] the question to clarify that requirement.  Anyway, if you want that then you need two generic type parameters, one which you specify and one which is inferred.  Unfortunately TS doesn't let you have such "partially inferred" type parameters in a single call, so the workaround involves currying [like this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOPVyN).  If that meets your needs I can write it up; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the key names of the arugment object in the return type, then that *whole* object needs to be part of the generic parameter.

```
type Input<A> = { [key: string]: A };
type Output<T> = { [key in keyof T]: null };

const track = <T extends Input<string>>(input: T): Output<T> => {
  return Object.entries(input).reduce((previous, [key, val]) => ({
    ...previous,
    [key]: null,
  }), {} as Output<T>);
}
```

Here, instead of capturing just the parameter from `Input<T>` you capture a whole input object as `T`. This has the type information about the keys on it, so those can be used on the output type.

Then call it like:

```
const result = track({ one: 'union', two: 'string' });
result.one // type is `null`, and has autocomplete
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=51&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAPAQQHxQLxQN5QDaA1hCAFxQDOwATgJZwDmAupWlAL4DcAsAFChIUAPLIkqACpZcBEmSiMopEAHsAZlElsocRABt9XPvwEBjVXBpQ6AQzPEcUFJKgQAHsAhwAJlVgIyCg0DMwYGAAUjBKUkgCUlGLAEi4yWHgCUFC0EMCItHCiAEYAVhBmwAB03nT0EFRRgcBxlTk+iGYQERFgOQBu9KqIVAA0RCpjfbb6LHE4WBEZ-FlZlWu9EANDo5kr8iA6eoYju5xxY3icULb+SSnScSacAuaW1jlUBsBOdg6LUJYIJQAOSIOCDODAsbAADuqhBIUYTGBXEeAg+X0qgKgAHocTZwNB6P4AAZHfQksa2XxQAAWN2uyFUFgAtmB9LkIC9+BYrN8CNirrgMfpgK8rKoOZV9KomBFAY8gA)

---

> *"but doing it this way seems to lose the autocomplete inside the Input, where I would like to specify the available possible strings that can be used."*

What I assume you mean is that this is allowed:

```
const result = track<'a' | 'b'>({ one: 'a', two: 'b' });
```

but this is an error:

```
const result = track<'a' | 'b'>({ one: 'a', two: 'c' });
//                                                ^ value not allowed
```

So here's the problem with that. This will require two generic parameters, one for the list of allowed values, and one for the argument being passed in. And you want to explicitly set one, and infer the other.

Typescript does not currently allow you to do. All generic parameters must be inferred, or all must be explicit.

You could delcare both with something like:

```
const track = <
  V extends string,
  T extends Input<V>
>(input: T): Output<T> => {
  //...
}

const result = track<
  'aa' | 'ab',
  { one: 'aa', two: 'ab' }
>({ one: 'aa', two: 'ab'});

result.one // type is `null`, and has autocomplete
```

But's that's not very satisfying.

And you can't infer both because the list of allowed values isn;'t in the list of arguments.

```
const result = track({ one: 'aa', two: 'ab'});
// the allowed values `V` here is simply inferred as `string`,
// which isn't helpful.
```

The typical work around is to break it up into the multiple function calls like so:

```
const track = <V extends string>() => {
  return <T extends Input<V>>(input: T): Output<T> => {
    return Object.entries(input).reduce((previous, [key, val]) => ({
      ...previous,
      [key]: null,
    }), {} as Output<T>);
  }
}

const result = track<'aa' | 'ab'>()({ one: 'aa', two: 'aa' });
//                               ^ note intermediate function call
result.one
```

Now the allowed values `V` can be explicitly set, with a function call. This then returns a new function where the argument type can be inferred.

It's not the most pleasant work around, but until Typescript gives us partial inference of generic parameters it's the best we got.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAPAQQHxQLxQN5QDaA1hCAFxQDOwATgJZwDmAupWlAL4DcAsAFChIUAPLIkqACpZcBEmSiMopEAHsAZlElsocRABt9XPvwEBjVXBpQ6AQzPEcUFADUoEAB7AIcACZVqOkYmDAAKAEocLDwBKChaCGBEWjhnSXcvH39YBGRXDDDGCUpJcMoxYAkUaSj8WLj4xOTUkQAjACsIM2AAOh8giCpQouRwnoTfRDMIUNCwBIA3elVEKgAaIhUNhdt9FkjsLFCY-gaGnov5iCWV9fqz+RAdPUM1+65wjbxOKFsAiqq0nCJjinAEYNM-AsVmAjSoBlhuDsDhQAHJbLZUVAAD5QdGtVFhcLHKCWCCUdGYjbAADuqgpGNRnGBAgS8P0vTJUAA9NybOBoPQAgADF76YUbWx+KAACz+v2QqgsAFswPpEhABOZLNYCFyfrg2QjtVZVOqevpVExQmTgUA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but doing it this way seems to lose the autocomplete inside the Input<A>, where I would like to specify the available possible strings that can be used.

Comment: I see... That makes things more complicated. See my update.

Comment: I had come to this conclusion today while working on it, but was hoping real hard that I was missing something. Thank you very much for the detailed answer!